# What could be the best design approach faster search?

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, solr, nosql

I am working on a architecture design of a application using PHP Yii which has large records(Around a million in future).
The DB struct is as below:

[image]

**Requirement:**

1. Fast Keyword Search for Profiles,Articles,Forums. Keyword can be combination of columns-e.g. BizName+City,City+Speciality,ServiceName+City,Article Title etc.
2. Keyword suggestion to user
3. Show search results in tabs. Example: Profiles,Articles.Forums etc.

**Approach 1:**

1. Have a relational DB.Write SQLs on multiple columns using OR and pattern matching.

**Cons:**

Poor performance

**Aprroach 2:**

1. Create a Keyword table.Create the combination of columns which are searchable and save them in KeywrodTab.
2. Create mapping tables of -keyword-Profile.Keyword-Article,Keyword-Forum etc.
3. Query keyword table for autosuggestions. once user hits search button query mapping tables and extract articleId,ProfileId,ForumId etc.

**Cons:**

Creating/Updating keywords and mapping on every update.

**Approach 3:**

1. Have a relational DB with FULLTEXT indices on searchable columns.

**Questions:**

1. Not sure if auto suggest for search box will work or not?
2. How will be the performance in this case as compared other approaches?

**Approach 4:**

Use NoSQL DB like MongoDB/Solr/Lucene in combination with RelationalDB.Use noSQL for finding the articleId,ProfileId,ForumId etc.And relational DB for displaying results.

**Cons:**

1. Creating/Updating noSQL on every update.

Any other approaches please? Which approach is scalable and will give good performance?

Comment: I would go for approach 4, and then make a intelligent script to delta update your indexes, refershing them totally once every couple of days (like Google does with their bot)

Comment: Approach 4. Solr can do incremental updates and you can have replication servers with writes/updates in one and reads on other servers and replication running continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to search quickly by multiple columns in multiple tables in an SQL database, you would need to place indexes on almost everything. That's a good way to get the write-performance of your relational database to record-lows.

For that reason I would recommend you to use an independent system for searching. From the technologies you mentioned I would rather recommend the dedicated search server Apache Solr (which is part of the Lucene project, not a separate technology) than MongoDB, because MongoDB is an interesting database technology a lots of great features, but its text search is not a core feature and rather tagged-on.

But technology-choices are always subjective, so evaluate all the options, see how they line up with your specific requirements and make your own decision.

Answer (score 1):

If you put it like that, approach 4 is the most scalable and has the best performance hands down.

However, as it's not clear what the content will actually be and how large the dataset will be - 'around a million rows' is hardly an indication, as it doesn't say what the rows contain and if those rows are in a single table or not - it's actually not possible to give accurate advice. Approach 4 may be the fastest anyway, but is it the most efficient? A million rows in a single table with about 4 columns, each containing about 250 bytes of data (just a guess here, your miles may vary), is actually not all that much. Choose the indexes well and optimize the queries, and a RDBMS may be all you need.

My suggestion is: build up a dataset to test with and try the various approaches.

Comment: Hi Plenka, I would also like to know the feasiblity of installing Solr from hosting perspective. We will have a PHP hosting enviroment. I belive, for Apache Solr, we need to have J2EE enviroment as well and it will be n/w call from PHP to J2EE server.

Comment: Yes, you'll need a JRE and a servlet container like Tomcat, Resin or Jetty. You could install those on the same server as the PHP hosting environment, but a separate server is recommended. By default Solr is queried over HTTP on another port than 80 (the default port on Tomcat is 8080). If you're using a Linux distribution as server OS odds are that these applications are readily available in the repositories, making the installation a breeze.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry, I have another question on this.Can I have auto suggest feature in the search box with Solr?